# Round Slider with CSS

Tags: css

What's the simplest way to do a round slider? given an input like this:

```
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="1" max="100">
```

This is just a regular straight input range, I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

Can this be done only with CSS or will I need JavaScript for this task?, if so, is there any easy to read example?, no jQuery, by the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this will help you https://codepen.io/XCanG/pen/pwPbmo

Answer (score 3):

Explanation:- You need to use jquery, roundslider.css & roundslider.js

```js
// you need to bind `.roundSlider()` with the `id = 'myRange'`.
$("#myRange").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    handleShape: "round",
    width: 22, // width of the roundSlider
    radius: 100, // radius size
    value: 60 // value you want to apply
});

$("#myRange1").roundSlider({
    width: 22, // width of the roundSlider
    radius: 100, // radius size
    value: 60 // value you want to apply
});
```

```css
#myRange {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="myRange">
<input type="range" id="myRange1">
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can make the white background of the inner circle transparent with this plugin?, also is it possible to display an element in the inner circle other than the value? Thanks

Comment: http://roundsliderui.com/document.html there are class names that can be overwritten. You could experiment with the background.

Comment: @Gilbert answer updated. but if you want to customise the slide you need to check documentation as mentioned by Gerard.

Comment: @Gilbert to make the roundslider inner as transparent you need to use the svg version of the round slider. refer the below demo where the background is transparent:
http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/drgkh0du/
.
.
Also you can use any custom element inside the circle instead of the value.
refer here: http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#custom-handle-shapes